# Firefox Profile Not Saved Passwords

Tags: firefox, password, windows-10

I've

1. Copied my Firefox profile from my Windows 10 PC.
2. Inserted it and renamed it in the `.mozilla` folder (renamed it to the default profile that was already in there and renamed the original default profile to `XXX.default.backup` in case I need it again).
3. Imported my bookmarks from the the "bookmarkbackups" folder
4. Opened Firefox.
   Firefox opens. My bookmarks are there. But non of my passwords have been saved.

I've looked through these forums but couldn't find this specific query (or solution). Any help would be greatly appreciated. And please be gentle - don't get too techhie - I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux.